# My flexbox containers are not responsive with flex-direction:column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i just started learning flexbox and i can't figure it out.

My header is responsive(kinda) and when i resize my browser window it works very good.
But container below with flex-direction:column behave very oddly(try resizing by yourself) it goes off my screen and elements inside stay on their places. And if i set it to flex-direction-row it works just as header.

how can i fix this?

link to the project: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-cerf-qbbwi?file=/index.html

```
    <style>
    header {
        width: 100%;
        background: #669966;
        height: 81px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        box-shadow: -2px 8px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    }
    
    .container {
        width: 1400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .header-wrap {
        width: 1400px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        height: 81px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0 50px;
    }
    
    .menu {
        width: 500px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .menu li {
        display: inline;
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 25px;
        color: #DFDFDF;
    }
    
    .header-login {
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 22px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .header-login li {
        display: inline;
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 22px;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .header-login li:last-child {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    
    .top-container1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .top-container1-top {
        width: 1400px;
        height: 120px;
        padding: 0 50px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    input[type="search"] {
        width: 341px;
        background: #F3F3F3;
        border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
        border-radius: 47px;
        height: 33px;
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    
    input[type="search"]:focus {
        border: none transparent;
    }
    .top-container1-info {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        flex-basis: 600px;
    }
    
    .top-info {
        height: 70px;
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #3F3F3F;
        text-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .top-info i {
        text-shadow: none;
        padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    }
    
    .top-info p:nth-child(2), .top-info p:nth-child(3) {
        color: #636363;
        text-shadow: none;
    }
    
    .top-container1-bot {
        width: 1400px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: flex-start;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    .top-container1-bot li {
        display: inline;
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 21px;
        color: #636363;
        padding: 0 46px 0 0;
    }
    .top-line {
        width: 732px;
        height: 5px;
        background: #F6F6F6;
        border-radius: 26px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .top-line span {
        width: 41px;
        height: 5px;
        border-radius: 26px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 8px;
        background-color: #669966;
    }

</style>
        <header>
    <div class="header-wrap">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>Доставка и оплата</li>
                <li>Отзывы</li>
                <li>О магазине</li>
                <li>Контакты</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="header-login">
                <ul>
                    <li>Вход</li>
                    <li>|</li>
                    <li>Регистрация</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="top-container1">
                <div class="top-container1-top">
                    <img src="img/logo.svg" width="149" height="54" alt="tea time logo">
                    <div class="top-container1-info">
                        <form>
                            <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск">
                        </form>
                        <div class="top-info">
                            <p><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>+375 (29) 765 45 65</p>
                            <p>Пн - пт с 9:00 до 19:00</p>
                            <p>Сб - вс выходной</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="top-container1-bot">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Чай</li>
                        <li>Кофе</li>
                        <li>Сладенькое</li>
                        <li>Атрибуты</li>
                        <li>Наборы</li>
                        <li>Акции</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="top-line">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask], [mcve] and post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must stop adding fixed width's

```
.top-container1-top {
        width: 1400px;
}
```

in you project for your different containers. That's what is messing things around in your code right now. Flexbox will take care of spacing for you, You just need to learn basic flexbox properties.

Here is the updated Working CodeSandBox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-cloud-ppz04?file=/index.html

Make small changes as per your requirement. Rest it's working fine now.

And for small screens apply media queries as per your requirement. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting width in % instead of a fixed value? This way your container isn’t stuck to the 1400px